# How do I return an array of attributes defined via a Rails model method, as well as the attributes in the database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, attributes, instance

I have a Rails model called Person which has database table columns for first_name and last_name. I've also defined a full_name method to return the combined first_name and last_name of the instance.

Is there a way to return an array, hash, or object which has first_name, last_name, as well as full_name?

Here's the code I have:

```
#person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name  

  def full_name
        self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
  end
end
```

Here's what I've tried in the Rails console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > person = Person.new({:first_name=>"Bruce", :last_name=>"Wayne"})
 => #<Person id: nil, first_name: "Bruce", :last_name: "Wayne", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

ruby-1.8.7-p302 > person.save!
 => true 

ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Person.last
 => #<Person id: 1, first_name: "Bruce", :last_name: "Wayne", created_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14", updated_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14">
```

Is it possible to get something returned like this instead:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Person.last
 => #<Person id: 1, first_name: "Bruce", :last_name: "Wayne", :full_name: "Bruce Wayne", created_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14", updated_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14">
```

Or can it only return values from the database?

Eventually, I'd like to be able to call `Person.all` to return an array of hashes which also includes full_name.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `first_name` and `last_name` are DB attributes which are printed in the inspect method.
If you want to access the `full_name` call `full_name` on the user object.

```
User.last.full_name
```

So if you want a hash of users with `full_name` as key:

```
@users = {}
User.all.each{|u| @users[u.full_name] = u}
```

**Edit 1**

The `User.last` call returns an `User` object. What gets printed in the console depends upon how the inspect method on the object is implemented. In case of ActiveRecord, database attributes are printed.

If you need the full name, you need to call the `full_name` method on the returned User object.

I am still not clear what you are trying to do.

**Edit 2**

```
u = User.last
[u.full_name, u.age, u.phone] # array
{:full_name => u.full_name, :age => u.age, :phone => u.phone } #hash
```

**Edit 3**

If you want to get a JSON format out of an object do the following

```
u.to_json(:methods => [:full_name])
```

Refer to the `to_json` [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) for more details.

**Edit 4**

The to_json method has `include` and `exclude` options for you to select the attributes you need. The to_json method gives you total control over data selection. Refer to the documentation link above for more details.

```
u.to_json(:methods => [:full_name], :include => [:first_name, :last_name])
```

If you need to include additional attributes, add them to the `:include` array in the above example.

**Edit 5**

To use this along with respond_with do the following:

```
respond_with(@users, :methods => [:full_name], 
                     :include => [:first_name, :last_name])
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to return all three: first_name, last_name, and full_name within one hash? Neither of your examples do that when i tried your code.

Comment: What do you mean by one hash? Expand your question to include an expected result.

Comment: Please see the third example in the question: `#<Person id: 1, first_name: "Bruce", :last_name: "Wayne", :full_name: "Bruce Wayne", created_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14", updated_at: "2010-11-09 22:53:14">`... first_name, last_name, and full_name are returned.

Comment: In other words, if I call Person.last... I'd like it to return something that includes full_name, as well as first_name and last_name. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. Will try gain... Right now, if call I User.last, I receive a user object that includes first_name, and last_name but not full_name within the array. To get full_name, I need to make a separate call, User.last.full_name. I'd like to get an array that will have all three, first_name, last_name, AND full_name. I'm thinking I will probably need to call a map method on the User object to add the full_name attribute to the array.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Why is it important that you access the User object using the array indexes? Describe how you are using the user object as hash/array for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks... sorry for being a newbie. I am making an app which makes an AJAX request to a Rails server. I need the Rails server to respond with a JSON formatted array which includes all of the DB attributes in addition to full_name attribute (which isn't a DB attribute). I have `render :json => User.last`, but it does not include the full_name attribute.

Comment: KandadaBoggu, I found another way to do it. Perhaps a bit crude... but gets what I was trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer with correct solution. We could have reached there long time ago if you had explicitly stated your requirement :-).

Comment: Kandada, looks like your solution only returns :full_name... as I've tried to state, I'd like to return all three... :first_name, :last_name, and :full_name.

Comment: Somehow, I think our wires are crossed. Beerlington's answer is pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks for trying to help tho!

Comment: I thought you didn't want first_name, and last_name that is why I added the exclude clause. Your current approach is very heavy handed for a problem  that can be addressed by the default to_json implementation.

Comment: Sorry, tried to make it clear that I wanted all three attributes in one array. The problem with calling User.last.to_json is that it wouldn't include the full_name attribute by default. It would only include first_name and last_name. And I couldn't figure out how to include it along with first_name and last_name as well. The core of the problem is how to return an array with BOTH the DB attributes of an object and the defined method attributes. Using Beerlington's method I was able to get it to work. Thanks for taking a look at the problem!

Comment: I see now that if I do `u.to_json(:methods => :full_name)` if will return both DB attributes and full_name! Thanks!

Comment: Also using `respond_to :json` and `respond_with(@user, :methods => :full_name)`. For an index action, this works: `respond_with(@users = User.all, :methods => :full_name)`

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head, it looks like a way to get an array of all DB attributes plus the full_name attribute is to do:

```
person = Person.last.attributes
person["full_name"] = Person.last.full_name
```

In console this will return something like:

```
=> {"first_name" => "Bruce", "created_at" => Tue Nov 09 22:53:14 UTC 2010, "updated_at" => Tue Nov 09 22:53:14 UTC 2010", "id" => 58, "last_name" => "Wayne", "full_name" => "Bruce Wayne"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for a single Person in one line with:

```
Person.first.instance_eval { attributes.merge("full_name" => full_name)}
```

Regarding your desire to Person.all and return hashes, why would you want this behavior? By default it returns an array of Person instances, and I wouldn't recommend overriding a default rails method to return a different type than you would normally expect. If you want this behavior, I would add a class method on Person, something like Person.all_hashes, that returns an array of hashes for each result.

Comment: Very helpful, I have to admit I thought that Person instances were themselves arrays... So, I couldn't understand why I could not insert another value into the Person instance. Sorry, very new to Ruby on Rails!

Comment: @GeekActive, since you found the answer helpful and accepted it, you should probably up-vote it too.